# terminal is not opening after uninstalling termite

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I have currently installed termite Terminal in my Ubuntu 18.04. But now I don't like this and so I uninstalled it by using `sudo apt remove --purge termite`, and then run my previous terminal but It is not opening so what should I do to keep on my previous terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official Ubuntu package for `termite`, you must have installed it from some 3rd party source.

`termite` requires `vte-ng` (not sure about the exact package name, might also depend on the source where you got `termite` from), which replaces the Ubuntu package `libvte-2.91-0` and probably its friends (`-common`, `-dev`) too.

For a long time, `vte-ng` was at version 0.50, whereas `gnome-terminal`  in Ubuntu 18.04 requires `libvte-2.91-0` version 0.52, 0.50 isn't new enough for that.

You should uninstall `vte-ng` and its related packages (whatever their exact names are), and reinstall `libvte-2.91-0` and friends from the Ubuntu repositories.

Another approach is to update `vte-ng` to 0.52, although if you've removed `termite` anyway then I'd rather reinstall the mainstream Ubuntu packages and not the `termite`-specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all open a TTY. Press, for example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> keys and log in.

Then check if the binary `gnome-terminal` is present in your system:

```
which gnome-terminal
```

The last command should return:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

Next check if the apt package for the `gnome-terminal` has been installed:

```
apt-show-versions | grep gnome-terminal
```

An finally reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```